# Ejecutar varias lineas en cmd desde python

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, rutas, powershell, exe

El problema es sencillo pero no consigo la respuesta en ninguna de las preguntas anteriormente formuladas.

Quiero abrir un ejecutable (.exe) que esta en la ruta `C:\Windows\System32`, `compmgmtlauncher.exe` exactamente.

Aquí es donde yo ya no se que hacer. No se cómo cambiar la ruta de donde cmd o powershell empiezan a buscar. En resumen lo que quiero hacer es:

```
C:\Users\Elquesea> cd\windows\system32    *ENTER*
C:\Windows\System32> compmgmtlauncher.exe
```

Y ahi ya se ejecutaría la aplicación.

Una de las cosas que me he dado cuenta es que en la barra de búsqueda de Windows si pones el nombre del ejecutable te aparece la opción "*ejecutar comando*", pero en el momento lo pones directamente en el cmd te indica que no hay ningún comando que se llame así. Aún así si pones `notepad.exe` te lo ejecuta perfectamente aun estando en el mismo directorio que la aplicación que quiero abrir.

¿Alguna idea?, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mete todos los comandos que quieras ejecutar en un archivo .bat y desde Python ejecuta ese .bat O si el problema sólo es llegar a la ruta donde está el ejecutable, no necesitas `cd` primero. Puedes pasar la ruta completa como nombre del ejecutable.

Comment: Vale, dos cositas: 1. He probado con `os.system`, `run`, `Popen` y `call`, pero en todos me salta el error `[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado`. Luego, 2. Cómo sería la sintaxis a la hora de crear el archivo .bat?

Comment: Pues supongo que `os.system(r"C:\Ruta\al\archivo.bat")` debería funcionar. Observa la `r` delante de la cadena, para señalar que es una cadena tipo "raw" en la que el carácter \ no es especial (de otro modo tendrías que duplicarlo \\ cada vez). El archivo .bat simplemente contiene en su interior comandos (uno por línea) como los que pondrías en la terminal.

Comment: Vale, el tema del .bat queda claro, pero no hay manera tío. Me sigue diciendo que no puede encontrarlo. He comprobado 3 veces la ruta y es la que he puesto, de hecho la he copiado y pegado, pero nada. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

En PowerShell, sería algo así:

```
Invoke-item -Path "C:\Windows\System32\compmgmtlauncher.exe"
```

En este caso lo abre y el script sigue ejecutando si tiene más líneas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes entrar en C:\Windows\System32 y buscar el nombre del comando de cmd que quieras ejecutar (Ej: Si quieres ejecutar un bat con taskkill busca un archivo que se llame taskkill.exe), lo copias, y lo pegas en el directorio en el que tengas tu archivo.py. Creo que el problema radica en que CMD trata de buscar los archivos .exe de los comandos que tiene en el directorio en el que se lo ejecute, y no en system 32, así que copiar los archivos de system 32 a tu carpeta del proyecto sería una solución viable. Al menos a mi me funcionó

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].